# Is there a way to configure the dbt lineage graph to start with a given set of settings?

Tags: dbt

I'm using DBT, and as you can imagine, my lineage DAG is fairly large by now.

I have it structured with tags - roughly aligned to bronze, silver, gold.

However, each time I open the DAG I typicaly have to go to tags and un-select a few to get to the "working" version of my dag.

Ideally I'd like the DBT lineage dag to default to:

[image]

And

[image]

But I don't see how to configure this.

(I'm using DBT cloud).

Comment: I don't think so. The docs site is just a SPA that get completely rebuilt every time you run `dbt docs generate` -- there is nowhere to store state like this. Wouldn't hurt to open an issue, though! This is the repo: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-docs